# How to programmatically create a new row and put that row in edit mode in Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my Kendo grid I am trying to put the 'create new item' button in the header (title) of the command column instead of the toolbar. Here is part of my grid definition:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
columns: [{ command: { name: "edit", title: "Edit", text: { edit: "", cancel: "", update: "" } },
headerTemplate: "<a onclick ='NewItemClick()' class='k-button k-button-icontext k-create-alert' id='new-item-button' title='Click to add a new item'><div>New Item</div></a>"},
```

My question is: how to create a new row and put that row in edit mode in 'NewItemClick()'

Comment: Could you post the full kendoGrid object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some troublesome scope issues when you try to bind the click event in the template definition itself.

Instead, it is easier to assign the link an ID, and then bind the click event later.  Notice that I've given it id=`create`.

```
headerTemplate: "<a id='create' class='k-button k-button-icontext k-create-alert' id='new-item-button' title='Click to add a new item'><div>New Item</div></a>"
```

Then in document ready, I bind the click event:

```
$("#create").click(function () {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    if (grid) {
        //this logic creates a new item in the datasource/datagrid
        var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
        var total = dataSource.data().length;
        dataSource.insert(total, {});
        dataSource.page(dataSource.totalPages());
        grid.editRow(grid.tbody.children().last());
    }
});
```

The above function creates a new row at the bottom of the grid by manipulating the datasource. Then it treats the new row as a row "edit". The action to create a new row was borrowed from OnaBai's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16712815/1860561).

Here is a working **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexyu/7SY5n/)**, hope it helps.

Comment: Glad it worked! Please accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark so other people know it's the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: As I hinted in my answer, you can see in your jsfiddle that if you sort by First Name ascending, it does not work

Answer (score 2):

I would like to complete on gisitgo's answer. If your datasource takes some time to update, when calling `page(...)`, then the refresh of the grid will cancel the editor's popup. This is averted by binding the call to editRow to the `"change"` event :

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
if (grid) {
  //this logic creates a new item in the datasource/datagrid
  var dataSource = grid.dataSource;
  var total = dataSource.data().length;
  dataSource.insert(total, {});
  dataSource.one("change", function () {
    grid.editRow(grid.tbody.children().last());
  });
  dataSource.page(dataSource.totalPages());
}
```

NB: This approach will yield problems if your grid is sorted because the new row will not necessarily be at the end

Answer (score 0):

I have found that issues might appear if you have multiple pages, such as the inserted row not opening up for edit. 
Here is some code based on the current index of the copied row.

We also edit the row based on UID for more accuracy.

```
function cloneRow(e) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var row = grid.select();

    if (row && row.length == 1) {
        var data = grid.dataItem(row);

        var indexInArray = $.map(grid.dataSource._data, function (obj, index)
        {
            if (obj.uid == data.uid)
            {
                return index;
            }
        });

        var newRowDataItem = grid.dataSource.insert(indexInArray, {
            CustomerId: 0,
            CustomerName: null,                
            dirty: true
        });
        var newGridRow = grid.tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + newRowDataItem.uid + "']");
        grid.select(newGridRow);
        grid.editRow(newGridRow);
        //grid.editRow($("table[role='grid'] tbody tr:eq(0)"));
    } else {
        alert("Please select a row");
    }
    return false;
}
```